# Wide to long with pivot_longer and mix of numeric and character data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
help <- data.frame(
        id  = c(100, 100, 101, 102, 102),
        q1 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 3),
        q2 = c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA),
        q3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 4, NA),
        q4 = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 5),
        group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c"))
    
    help$group <- as.character(help$group)
```

I am trying to pivot longer so dataset looks like this:

```
id  score group
100 NA    a
100 1     b
100 NA    c
...
```

But I get an error with the numeric values of q1-q4 and the character string `group`.

```
pivot_longer(help, !id, names_to = "score", 
             values_to = "group", values_ptypes = list(group = 'character'))
Error: Can't convert <double> to <character>.
```

How can I pivot longer but also preserve the group variable (where there is several missing data for the q1-4 there is a match for every id and group)?

Comment: `pivot_longer(help, -c(id, group))` or even `pivot_longer(help, !c(id, group))`

Comment: i had a feeling it was going to be very simple. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)

output <- pivot_longer(help, -c(id, group), names_to = "question", 
             values_to = "score") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-question) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(id, group)
```

Output

```
head(output)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id group score
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1   100 a        NA
2   100 a         1
3   100 a        NA
4   100 a        NA
5   100 b         1
6   100 b        NA
```